# Chmod not working for a directory in VIRTUAL SFTP Server

Tags: java, sftp, file-permissions, jsch, chmod

Below is the code I've used for chmod

```
channelSftp.cd("test");
channelSftp.mkdir("8696");
channelSftp.chmod(511, "8696");
```

This is the stack trace when I try to chmod a folder in sftp virtual server...

```
May 9, 2017 5:31:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2339 ms
2: No such file or directory
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873)
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._setStat(ChannelSftp.java:2418)
com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.chmod(ChannelSftp.java:2085)
automate.turbosite.Automate.SFTPCreateFolder(Automate.java:208)
automate.turbosite.Automate.initiate(Automate.java:304)
automate.turbosite.AutomateServlet.doGet(AutomateServlet.java:51)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

But the same is working when it's an actual SFTP Server and not a virtual SFTP Server.

If it's a virtual SFTP Server, am not getting any errors when doing chmod for Files, but am getting exception when i try to do chmod for a folder(directory) and it says No such File or directory but as you can see i've created that directory using mkdir in the before line only)

Comment: Note: 511 is decimal representation that corresponds to 777.

Comment: I see the stack trace but there is no error message here. Did you not paste it or don't you have any?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out; i missed it while copy pasting the stack trace..and i have edited the question now along with the error

Comment: Can you please verify if `mkdir` succeeded in creating the directory?

Comment: yes mkdir has succeeded in creating the directory. Am able to see the directory 8696 in virtual SFTP file server.